# Reducing the number of MySQL processes to save memory

Tags: mysql, memory

I have just started the MySQL server on my Ubuntu machine, and I see this in `htop`:

[image]

There are many mysql processes, each of which takes 4.2% memory. Since I am short on memory, I would like to reduce the number of processes. How can I do this? And will it really help me reduce the memory consumption?

EDIT: I am on a DigitalOcean droplet, Ubuntu 22.04, with 4 GB available RAM. The relevant configuration is in file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` (all comments removed):

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address     = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP


log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
max_binlog_size   = 100M

performance_schema = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly provide more details? Available RAM on server, my.cnf settings, etc. In general DMBS tend to perform better the more memory is assigned to the database instance. Data and execution plans are stored in memory to reduce the overtime of producing new plans and/or removing data from the buffer cache. Hit [edit] and add as much details as possible to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what you see is actually a single multi-threaded `mysqld` process consuming 4.2% of your memory *in total*. This is due to the way `htop` reports memory usage, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335569/memory-report-confusion-shown-by-top-and-htop-commands). Most of the memory reported is shared between the threads, although each thread also allocates some private memory.

Secondly, MySQL spawns a separate thread for each connected client (in addition to all the background threads), so the way to reduce the number of threads would be to reduce the maximum number of allowed connections.

Comment: So the reason I see ~25 threads in htop is that there are 25 connected clients? This does not make sense: there are only 2-3 people who work with this database. Also, I see this number of threads even after I do `service mysql restart`. Does MySQL keep a minimum number of "idle" threads even if no people are connectred? If yes, is there a way to reduce the number of these idle threads?

Comment: "connected client (in addition to all the background threads)"

Comment: So there are ~25 background threads? Are these just idle threads waiting for connections? Or do they have some important job even when no user is connected?

Comment: Perhaps [reading the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/thread-information.html) can help. Why are you so concerned about the number of threads MySQL is creating?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InnoDB (not MyISAM), `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the critical tunable.  For 4GB of *available* RAM, 1500M might be safe and useful.

Check `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`  Hopefully it is much less than `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';`  If so, then lower `max_connections` to decrease the number of processes.

Do you really have 25 different clients?  Or are many of them simply not going away, perhaps because the connection was not explicitly closed?